# I need to add a fitting line to a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, linear-regression

I am interested in adding a fitting line (linear regression) only to the linear part of a plot

```
filename = 'data_250var600.txt' ;
P=load( filename ) ;


f00 = figure;
plot(P(:,1),P(:,2),'-bx',...
     P(:,1),P(:,3),'--mo',...
     P(:,1),P(:,4),'--gs')

xlabel('Time, ms');
ylabel('Variance, mm^2');
hleg1 = legend('07','08','09','location','SouthEast');
title('data250var600') % title


P=[
100     732.7318272 2301.212628
200     2022.799407 4836.512573
300     3790.328395 6307.281793
400     5781.509551 7390.353428
500     7932.264606 7588.719506
600     9583.048356 7602.084801
700     10017.79108 7168.106741
800     10007.80916 7031.052248
900     9359.477015 7747.909733
1000    9256.611609 8373.799535
1100    9824.423253 8755.180075
1200    10281.3222  8729.212879
1300    10421.7682  8824.199107
1400    10908.09722 8872.63802
1500    11590.61608 8993.919216
1600    12056.20738 9198.947131
1700    12785.47621 9261.411574
1800    13027.82142 9242.737465
1900    13109.53144 9764.176206
2000    13806.27964 9963.253109
]
```

Comment: `P` is of dimension `1x60`?

Comment: Do you mean this [matlab linear regression](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html). Seems quite straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

So what is your actual question? Is it how to determine where the linear part begins and ends or how to do the regression?
You somehow need to determine where the linear part begins and where it ends. Once you determined this you can simply use a combination of polyfit() and polyval()

```
% linear part for blue maybe from index 10 to end
f = polyfit(P(10:end,1), P(10:end,2), 1);
y = polyval(f, P(10:end,1));
plot(P(10:end,1),y,'b-')

% linear part for magenta part maybe from index 3 to end
f = polyfit(P(3:end,1), P(3:end,3), 1);
y = polyval(f, P(3:end,1));
plot(P(3:end,1),y,'m-')
```